# How to make the PNG's transparent region not be listened by the EventListener when a touch event happened?

Tags: coronasdk

I didn't find a variable that could make the PNG picture's transparent region not being touched. 
Does DisplayObject have a function or variable that could make that transparent region can't be touched?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

you need to use a mask to disable the transparent touch, please refer to this tutorial:
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/05/29/how-to-use-bitmap-masks/

Comment: The mask hides a visible area. @Hexor asked that *the transparent region not being touched*

Comment: @vovahost yes it dose, but if you use this property (.isHitTestMasked = true) then it will do what Hexor asked.

quote from the link:"Thankfully, this if very easy to do once an image is masked. To disable touches on the masked (transparent) regions of an object, you simply set the object.isHitTestMasked property to true.

fruit.isHitTestMasked = true"

Answer (score 1):

I don't remeber any function but you can divide your picture in pieces. Or you can use sprite sheets and select the desired area.